# Can you have a moon that rotates 21 times per orbit?

Tags: moons, orbital-mechanics, gas-giants

I want to avoid having my earthlike moon of a gas giant be tidally locked. Now I know that 3:2 or even 5:2 resonance is possible, but what about 21:1 for my moon? Is that too many rotations per orbit to be realistic?

Comment: That depends on the Orbital period. Earth spins a lot more than 21 times in her orbit around the sun.

Comment: Check out the graphic in [this NASA article](https://science.nasa.gov/moon/tidal-locking/). You'll notice Charon and Pluto are tidally locked, but check out that outer moon of Pluto that's spinning like a top. 21:1 will work just fine, so long as the mass ratio and distance between the masses is reasonable.

Comment: I think it will be tricky to arrange. An earthlike world is _big_, and that means the tidal between it and its parent will be pretty strong, and unless its fellow moons are similarly pretty big their influence on it will be limited. The outer moon of pluto is small, and it orbits a long way from its parent, but that relative orbital distance is harder to arrange in the inner solar system where the gravitational influence of the star is that much stronger.

Comment: @ErikHall I don't think earth's day length due to orbital resonances, but just regular slow tidal deceleration.

Comment: Orbital resonances? You mean there's perhaps another moon further out or closer for it to resonate with?

Comment: @Escapeddentalpatient. if it were a gas giant moon, it would be surprising if there _weren't_ a whole bunch of other moons in the neighbourhood.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those "yes, but..." moments.

Trivially, it is entirely possible to have fast-rotating moons... as JBH pointed out in the comments, Pluto's moon [Hydra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydra_(moon)) has an orbital period of ~38.2 Earth-days, and a rotational period of ~.43 Earth-days and so squeezes in ~89 Hydra-days per Hydra-orbit (which I'd call a month, but opinions vary on that). Hydra has a 1:6 *orbital* resonance with Charon but its own rotation is somewhat chaotic and its axis moves around quite a bit so it doesn't have a *spin* resonance as such. Hydra's very small size and weird shape, distance from and relatively small size of Pluto-Charon have all combined to set up this situation, and it isn't necessarily one that will generalize, especially to something of Earthlike size and mass.

The problem is, at least in part, adding in enough other large objects to resonate with. The objects have to be large, because an Earthlike moon is going to be large. You need your moon's orbit to be eccentric (because circular orbits generally end up in 1:1 spin-orbit resonances, which isn't what you want) but having a large eccentricity around a gas giant is awkward without having massive objects orbiting further out and you start running short on space before things start falling outside of the [Hill Sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_sphere) and being flung off into deep space (or at least into a less interesting dwarf-planet future instead of being an exciting moon with a nice view).

Working out exactly how the resonances arise is tricky (take a look at [Spin-orbit coupling for close-in planets](https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.14335v1) if you were feeling keen) but when it comes to resonances and orbital forcing things just seem to fall into *low* resonances because they're more energetically favorable. Your 21:1 resonance seems pretty fragile even if it *could* occur (which isn't clear) it seems like it wouldn't take much to disrupt it and end up with something less interesting. I also suspect (but am not at all certain) that high resonances like the one you're suggesting might involve considerable tidal heating, Io-style, which you probably don't want. Don't take my word on that one, though.

Consider instead having a lower resonance and a closer orbit to the primary. A night that lasts a couple of Earth-days is not an insurmountable obstacle to habitability, especially when combined with a thick atmosphere with [superrotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_super-rotation). The parent planet will look more exciting when you're closer to it, and you'll be better protected by its magnetosphere.

Answer (score -1):

This all is possible, but so the numbers (both nominator and denominator) grow in the ratios, so is becoming the orbit lesser and lesser stable. But still there are interesting ratios.

For example, there is a 19 years long ratio between the lunar month and solar year. With other words, it takes 19 years, that the Moon and the Earth become exactly on the same place around the Sun.

Comment: Ugh, no there is no such thing *exactly*. 19 tropical years are only *approximately* equal to 235 synodic months; the difference is about 2 hours 4 minutes 58 seconds. A synodic month (which is *not* the orbital period of the Moon) is on the average 29 days 12 hours 44 minutes 2.9 seconds, or 708 hours 44 minutes 2.9 seconds.

Comment: @AlexP Are you sure? Afaik a lot of things, like the beginning of the Easter depends on this.

Comment: 708h 44m 2.9s × 235 = 599,589,081.5 seconds. 365.24219 days × 19 = 599,581,579.1 seconds. See [Metonic cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonic_cycle). (There is no reason why would expect to have an exact common multiple of two completely unrelated numbers.)